# setxkbmap equivalent in a Yocto Project based Distro

Tags: yocto, raspberry-pi4, opkg

```
setxkbmap it
```

doesn't work.
How i configure the keyboard layout in RDK Video IP (A Yocto Project based Distro)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is simply:

```
loadkeys it
```

Equivalent at:

```
loadkeys /usr/share/keymaps/i386/qwerty/it.map.gz
```